# How to access docker container's ssh key from VSCode

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-devcontainer

I have a devcontainer project which starts two containers - one for the ASP.Net app I am developing and one for Postgres. The code for the app is pulled from local git repo directly on the container, nothing on my host. I have a specific ssh key, which is copied to the container (don't worry, it is with very restricted rights, I am aware that it is not a good idea to copy ssh keys in the container) and I use that key to access the local repo.

On the container the key works good, the source code is pulled successfully from the repo.

I use the VSCode Git extension to stage changes and commit them. But when I try to push, it gives an authentication error. If I try to run a `git push` from the VSCode Terminal it asks for the password.

The only way to push or pull is to connect to the docker container and manually execute the command from there. In that case it uses the ssh key and does not ask for a password.

So my question: Is there a way to force the Git extension to use the ssh key in the docker container, or somehow execute the git commands directly in the container? You know, like instead of calling `git push` on the context of the host or VSCode, execute it in the context of the docker container.

Thanks.